# NumPy phase factor, (-1)^n: performance

Tags: python, numpy

In some areas of physics, phase factors such as (-1)^n, where n is some integer formed from summing or subtracting other integers, often appear. Is there, in general, any performance improvement to the following:

```
sgn = lambda k: -1 if k % 2 else 1
```

over simply

```
sgn = (-1)**k
```

And if so, what would be the best way to vectorize the former?

**Edit:** Mr E has provided a fast solution for `k` bounded in some integer range, but I'm a bit concerned that my `k` might fall outside this range. Initially I thought of:

```
In [1]: sg = np.array([1,-1])
In [2]: k = np.array([201, 0, 2, -37])
In [3]: sg[k % 2]
Out[4]: array([-1,  1,  1, -1])
```

But the modulus operation seems to slow it down compared with the power approach:

```
ph1 = lambda k: (-1)**k
sgn = np.array([1,-1])
ph2 = lambda k: sgn[k % 2]

x = np.random.randint(-200, 200, 100)
%timeit ph1(x)
1000000 loops, best of 3: 264 ns per loop

%timeit ph2(x)
1000000 loops, best of 3: 284 ns per loop
```

Comment: Why does this sound like 1:1 copied question from some homework assignment? :D

Comment: This is a genuine question not related to homework (which I haven't had to do for some time...)

Comment: Is `k` an array of integers here?

Comment: Yes `k` can only be a scalar integer or a sequence of such.

Comment: Thanks - I think this is what I've already put in my edit above. The problem is that I've found it to be slower than simply `(-1)**k` which is already vectorized.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [`tile`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.tile.html) function to do this efficiently. Example:

```
>>> np.tile([1, -1], 10)
array([ 1, -1,  1, -1,  1, -1,  1, -1,  1, -1,  1, -1,  1, -1,  1, -1,  1,
       -1,  1, -1])
```

Alternatively, if you are summing a series `(-1)^k a_k` and you have already computed `a_k`, as a numpy array, you can sum `a_k[::2]` and `a_k[1::2]` and take the difference. This avoids computing the alternating sign and multiplying.

To answer your edited question:

```
>>> k = np.array([1, 3, 2, 5, 10, 7])
>>> foo = np.array([1, -1])
>>> foo[k % 2]
array([-1, -1,  1, -1,  1, -1])
>>>
```

Comment: This would work if I could be sure that k is in the range -19 to 19, but in general that might not be the case. Perhaps `sg = np.arrray([1,-1]); sg[k % 2]`?

Answer (score 2):

[Mr E has answered how to vectorise it with numpy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27361263/3005188), but with respect to which of those is more efficient time wise, the following code uses `timeit` for various values of `k` and plots the results using matplotlib.

The results suggest that using `-1 if k % 2 else 1` is consistently faster than using `(-1)**k`.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

from timeit import Timer

def f1(k): return -1 if k % 2 else 1
def f2(k): return (-1)**k

result1 = []
result2 = []

x = range(0,1000, 100)
for n in x:
    print(n)

    timer1 = Timer('f1({})'.format(n), setup='from __main__ import f1')
    timer2 = Timer('f2({})'.format(n), setup='from __main__ import f2')

    result1.append(timer1.timeit(100000))
    result2.append(timer2.timeit(100000))

plt.plot(x, result1, label='-1 if k % 2 else 1')
plt.plot(x, result2, label='(-1)**k')

plt.xlabel('k')
plt.ylabel('Time')

plt.legend(loc='best')

plt.show()
```

[image: Example plot]

Comment: You can pass callable objects directly to `timeit.Timer()` (or `timeit.timeit()`).